# How to trigger resize function automatically

Tags: jquery

I just used the following code to detach elements according to window size:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(event){
   if ($(window).width() < 1000){
        $("div.products_left .left_box").detach().insertBefore("div.products_left div.content.flex"); 
        $(".image-container-split").detach().appendTo(".image-container.image-container-col-2");
    }
    else{
        $("div.products_left .left_box").detach().insertAfter("div.products_left div.content.flex"); 
    }
});
```

But then I noticed that for the code to work, I have to physically resize the window, which I can't do on mobile devices.

How can I allow the code to run immediate after the page loads and on any device?

Comment: `$(window).trigger('resize')` http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 0):

Set your code in your navigation bar menu click event

```
function resizewin()
    if ($(window).width() < 1000){
            $("div.products_left .left_box").detach().insertBefore("div.products_left div.content.flex"); 
            $(".image-container-split").detach().appendTo(".image-container.image-container-col-2");
        }
        else{
            $("div.products_left .left_box").detach().insertAfter("div.products_left div.content.flex"); 
        }
}
```

set this function in onclick attr of your menu bar action link